# Rotate an YUV byte array on Android

Tags: android, rotation, arrays, yuv

I'm looking to rotate a YUV frame preview recieved from a Preview Callblack, so far I've founded this post which cointains an algorithm to rotate the frame preview but is messing the preview image 
[camera pixels rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853401/camera-pixels-rotated)

another way to rotate the image will be creating a jpg out of the YUV image, create a bitmap, rotate a bitmap and obtaining the byte array of the bitmap, but I really need the format in YUV (NV21).

FYI. the reason I'm asking this is because I have a camera app that supports rotation, but the frame previews are coming back in landscape mode only.

Comment: I've also come across this problem and ended up using the solution you mention using `Bitmap` to rotate the image and use JPEG instead. Indeed setting the display orientation does not affect the buffer received by `PreviewCallback` as mentioned by the documentation: _This does not affect the order of byte array passed in onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos._

Comment: Hi. Did you managed to solve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following method can rotate a YUV420 byte array by 90 degree.

```
private byte[] rotateYUV420Degree90(byte[] data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) 
{
    byte [] yuv = new byte[imageWidth*imageHeight*3/2];
    // Rotate the Y luma
    int i = 0;
    for(int x = 0;x < imageWidth;x++)
    {
        for(int y = imageHeight-1;y >= 0;y--)                               
        {
            yuv[i] = data[y*imageWidth+x];
            i++;
        }
    }
    // Rotate the U and V color components 
    i = imageWidth*imageHeight*3/2-1;
    for(int x = imageWidth-1;x > 0;x=x-2)
    {
        for(int y = 0;y < imageHeight/2;y++)                                
        {
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth*imageHeight)+(y*imageWidth)+x];
            i--;
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth*imageHeight)+(y*imageWidth)+(x-1)];
            i--;
        }
    }
    return yuv;
}
```

(Note that this might only work if the width and height is a factor of 4)

Comment: Thanks it really helps me!
but i have a little problem
When i apply this code snippet on my data bytes my image rotate to (-90).
i want to rotate to +90. or in simple words need to rotate in opposite direction
can you please help me out thanks!

Comment: @Usama: did you find a solution for rotating it the other way? I'm stuck here as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yes i call same function 3 time,pass return data as a argument to the next call and exchange width height parameters..

Comment: image is rotated clockwise 90deg but color mismatch. I'm in doubt whether buffer I received (from external lib) is YUV or not. If I dump the received buffer directly to a file and play with ffplay  its playing fine
ffplay -v info -f rawvideo  -video_size 320x240 yuv.bin

Answer (score 11):

Here are the options to turn a different corner (90, 180, 270):

```
public static byte[] rotateYUV420Degree90(byte[] data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
    byte[] yuv = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2];
    // Rotate the Y luma
    int i = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = imageHeight - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            yuv[i] = data[y * imageWidth + x];
            i++;
        }
    }
    // Rotate the U and V color components
    i = imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2 - 1;
    for (int x = imageWidth - 1; x > 0; x = x - 2) {
        for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight / 2; y++) {
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth * imageHeight) + (y * imageWidth) + x];
            i--;
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth * imageHeight) + (y * imageWidth)
                    + (x - 1)];
            i--;
        }
    }
    return yuv;
}

private static byte[] rotateYUV420Degree180(byte[] data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
    byte[] yuv = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2];
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = imageWidth * imageHeight - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        yuv[count] = data[i];
        count++;
    }
    i = imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2 - 1;
    for (i = imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2 - 1; i >= imageWidth
            * imageHeight; i -= 2) {
        yuv[count++] = data[i - 1];
        yuv[count++] = data[i];
    }
    return yuv;
}

public static byte[] rotateYUV420Degree270(byte[] data, int imageWidth,
                                     int imageHeight) {
    byte[] yuv = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2];
    int nWidth = 0, nHeight = 0;
    int wh = 0;
    int uvHeight = 0;
    if (imageWidth != nWidth || imageHeight != nHeight) {
        nWidth = imageWidth;
        nHeight = imageHeight;
        wh = imageWidth * imageHeight;
        uvHeight = imageHeight >> 1;// uvHeight = height / 2
    }
    // ??Y
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++) {
        int nPos = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++) {
            yuv[k] = data[nPos + i];
            k++;
            nPos += imageWidth;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i += 2) {
        int nPos = wh;
        for (int j = 0; j < uvHeight; j++) {
            yuv[k] = data[nPos + i];
            yuv[k + 1] = data[nPos + i + 1];
            k += 2;
            nPos += imageWidth;
        }
    }
    return rotateYUV420Degree180(yuv, imageWidth, imageHeight);
}
```

Comment: Your method to rotate 270º it's applying a mirror effect on the image. The right solution should be : `return rotateYuv420Degree180(rotateYuv420Degree90(data,  imageWidth, imageHeight), imageWidth, imageHeight);`

There is no sense to rotate 90º in a different way that your original `rotateYuv420Degree90` method

Comment: note that these methods are pretty heavy and may impact performance significantly, especially when you call two like above suggested by Francisco. may be fine for taking picture/single frame, but "live processing" (e.g. when streaming) won't be possible, especially on slower/older devices. these methods may be also written in pure/native C/C++ (NDK) or RenderScript code, few times more efficient

Comment: @snachmsm , Is there existing library doing this?

Comment: yes, best of the best is [libyuv](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libyuv/), but you need to implement this native component by yourself... well, I did that, but now I see in search results that someone build a [wrapper/port for Android](https://github.com/crow-misia/libyuv-android), worth check

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it

This block of code is setup elsewhere

```
    Camera.Size size
    Rect rectangle = new Rect();
    rectangle.bottom = size.height;
    rectangle.top = 0;
    rectangle.left = 0;
    rectangle.right = size.width;
```

This is the method that does the work

```
    private Bitmap rotateBitmap(YuvImage yuvImage, int orientation, Rect rectangle)
    {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(rectangle, 100, os);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(orientation);
    byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0 , 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

compress the YUVImage into a JPEG so that bitmap can handle it. Rotate the bitmap and then export it. To get it back to a JPEG which is how I wanted it I used this line

```
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outputStream);
```

Comment: This may cause artefacts and will be slow since there is an extra JPEG encode/decode step. Wouldn't recommend for anything else than testing.

Comment: Too slow, see Sami comments above

Comment: It's simple to implement and understand making it easier to deploy than some of the other answer. It is a tiny bit slower than the absolute optimal solution but for images that may only be rotated once in their lives, it's perfectly acceptable.