# Scaling YUV420 Image using libyuv produces weird output

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk, tensorflow-lite, libyuv

Possible duplicate of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960251/problems-when-scaling-a-yuv-image-using-libyuv-library) question with major parts picked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677747/how-to-find-out-resolution-and-count-of-frames-in-yuv-420-file). I've tried whatever solutions were provided there, they don't work for me.

**Background**

I'm capturing an image in [YUV_420_888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888) image format returned from ARCore's `frame.acquireCameraImage()` method. Since I've set the camera configuration at 1920*1080 resolution, I need to scale it down to 224*224 to pass it to my tensorflow-lite implementation. I do that by using [LibYuv](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/) library through the Android NDK.

**Implementation**

Prepare the image frames

```
    //Figure out the source image dimensions
    int y_size = srcWidth * srcHeight;

    //Get dimensions of the desired output image
    int out_size = destWidth * destHeight;

    //Generate input frame
    i420_input_frame.width = srcWidth;
    i420_input_frame.height = srcHeight;
    i420_input_frame.data = (uint8_t*) yuvArray;
    i420_input_frame.y = i420_input_frame.data;
    i420_input_frame.u = i420_input_frame.y + y_size;
    i420_input_frame.v = i420_input_frame.u + (y_size / 4);

    //Generate output frame
    free(i420_output_frame.data);
    i420_output_frame.width = destWidth;
    i420_output_frame.height = destHeight;
    i420_output_frame.data = new unsigned char[out_size * 3 / 2];
    i420_output_frame.y = i420_output_frame.data;
    i420_output_frame.u = i420_output_frame.y + out_size;
    i420_output_frame.v = i420_output_frame.u + (out_size / 4);
```

I scale my image using Libyuv's `I420Scale` method

```
libyuv::FilterMode mode = libyuv::FilterModeEnum::kFilterBox;
jint result = libyuv::I420Scale(i420_input_frame.y, i420_input_frame.width,
                                i420_input_frame.u, i420_input_frame.width / 2,
                                i420_input_frame.v, i420_input_frame.width / 2,
                                i420_input_frame.width, i420_input_frame.height,
                                i420_output_frame.y, i420_output_frame.width,
                                i420_output_frame.u, i420_output_frame.width / 2,
                                i420_output_frame.v, i420_output_frame.width / 2,
                                i420_output_frame.width, i420_output_frame.height,
                                mode);
```

and return it to java

```
    //Create a new byte array to return to the caller in Java
    jbyteArray outputArray = env -> NewByteArray(out_size * 3 / 2);
    env -> SetByteArrayRegion(outputArray, 0, out_size, (jbyte*) i420_output_frame.y);
    env -> SetByteArrayRegion(outputArray, out_size, out_size / 4, (jbyte*) i420_output_frame.u);
    env -> SetByteArrayRegion(outputArray, out_size + (out_size / 4), out_size / 4, (jbyte*) i420_output_frame.v);
```

Actual image : [image]

What it looks like post scaling :

[image]

What it looks like if I create an Image from the `i420_input_frame` without scaling :

[image]

Since the scaling messes up the colors big time, tensorflow fails to recognize objects properly. (It recognizes properly in their sample application) **What am I doing wrong to mess up the colors big time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either I was doing something wrong (Which I couldn't fix) or LibYuv does not handle colors properly while dealing with YUV images from Android.

Refer official bug posted on Libyuv library : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/libyuv/issues/detail?id=815&can=1&q=&sort=-id

They suggested I use a method `Android420ToI420()` first and then I apply whatever transformations I need. I ended up using `Android420ToI420()` first, then Scaling, then transformation to RGB. In the end, the output was slightly better than the cup image posted above but the distorted colors were still present. I ended up using OpenCV to shrink the image and convert it to RGBA or RGB formats.

```
// The camera image received is in YUV YCbCr Format at preview dimensions
// so we will scale it down to 224x224 size using OpenCV
// Y plane (0) non-interleaved => stride == 1; U/V plane interleaved => stride == 2
// Refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888
val cameraPlaneY = cameraImage.planes[0].buffer
val cameraPlaneUV = cameraImage.planes[1].buffer

// Create a new Mat with OpenCV. One for each plane - Y and UV
val y_mat = Mat(cameraImage.height, cameraImage.width, CvType.CV_8UC1, cameraPlaneY)
val uv_mat = Mat(cameraImage.height / 2, cameraImage.width / 2, CvType.CV_8UC2, cameraPlaneUV)
var mat224 = Mat()
var cvFrameRGBA = Mat()

// Retrieve an RGBA frame from the produced YUV
Imgproc.cvtColorTwoPlane(y_mat, uv_mat, cvFrameRGBA, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGRA_NV21)


//Then use this frame to retrieve all RGB channel data
//Iterate over all pixels and retrieve information of RGB channels
  for(rows in 1 until cvFrameRGBA.rows())
      for(cols in 1 until cvFrameRGBA.cols()) {
          val imageData = cvFrameRGBA.get(rows, cols)
          // Type of Mat is 24
          // Channels is 4
          // Depth is 0
          rgbBytes.put(imageData[0].toByte())
          rgbBytes.put(imageData[1].toByte())
          rgbBytes.put(imageData[2].toByte())
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The color problem is caused because you are working with a different YUV format. The YUV format that camera frameworks use is YUV NV21. **This format (NV21) is the standard picture format on Android camera preview. YUV 4:2:0 planar image, with 8 bit Y samples, followed by interleaved V/U plane with 8bit 2x2 subsampled chroma samples.**

If your colors are inversed, it means that:

- You are working **with a YUV NV12** (plane U is V and V is U).
- One of your color planes is doing something weird.

To work properly with `libyuv` I suggest you to convert your camera output to a YUV I420 using `transformI420` method and sending the format by parameter:

```
return libyuv::ConvertToI420(src, srcSize, //src data
                             dstY, dstWidth, //dst planes
                             dstU, dstWidth / 2,
                             dstV, dstWidth / 2,
                             cropLeft, cropTop, //crop start
                             srcWidth, srcHeight, //src dimensions
                             cropRight - cropLeft, cropBottom - cropTop, //dst dimensions
                             rotationMode,
                             libyuv::FOURCC_NV21); //libyuv::FOURCC_NV12
```

After do this conversion you will be able to properly work with libyuv using all the `I420scale`, `I420rotate`... and so on. Your scale method should look like:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_aa_project_images_yuv_myJNIcl_scaleI420(JNIEnv *env, jclass type,
                                                 jobject srcBufferY,
                                                 jobject srcBufferU,
                                                 jobject srcBufferV,
                                                 jint srcWidth, jint srcHeight,
                                                 jobject dstBufferY,
                                                 jobject dstBufferU,
                                                 jobject dstBufferV,
                                                 jint dstWidth, jint dstHeight,
                                                 jint filterMode) {

    const uint8_t *srcY = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(srcBufferY));
    const uint8_t *srcU = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(srcBufferU));
    const uint8_t *srcV = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(srcBufferV));
    uint8_t *dstY = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(dstBufferY));
    uint8_t *dstU = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(dstBufferU));
    uint8_t *dstV = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(dstBufferV));

    return libyuv::I420Scale(srcY, srcWidth,
                             srcU, srcWidth / 2,
                             srcV, srcWidth / 2,
                             srcWidth, srcHeight,
                             dstY, dstWidth,
                             dstU, dstWidth / 2,
                             dstV, dstWidth / 2,
                             dstWidth, dstHeight,
                             static_cast<libyuv::FilterMode>(filterMode));
}
```

If you want to convert this image to a JPEG after all the process. You can use `I420toNV21` method and after that use the android native conversion from YUV to JPEG. Also you can use [libJpegTurbo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libjpeg-turbo/) which is a complementary library for this kind of situations.