# Rotate YUV420Sp image by 90 degrees counter clockwise

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, yuv, libyuv

I want to rotate YUV420SP image by 90 counter clockwise. Image size is 640*480, so the rotated image size becomes 480*640 which i don't want, So i want to extract 480*480 data (or any other square size) and rotate that data.

I have seen : [Rotate an YUV byte array on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167976/rotate-an-yuv-byte-array-on-android)

But this answer rotates 90 clockwise.

Can somebody suggest some function which rotates YUV420Sp data by 90(counter clockwise) or by 270 degrees (clockwise) without changing image dimensions.

Comment: I solved this in my android app but it's in native code that I use via JNI. Would you want to see a solution in C++ or you want Java only?

Comment: i want native code, can you please write your code here . Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here's my native code that evolved after much banging of the head.

My difficulty was that I didn't understand planar image formats until I saw [this](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#IYUV) and this:

[image: YUV420SP NV21 image format]

Here are the 2 functions I eventually wrote:

```
// rotate luma image plane 90*
//
//             (dst direction)
//                 ------>
//      dst -> +-------------+
//             |^            |
//             |^ (base dir) |
//             |^            |
//     base -> +-------------+ <- endp
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void rotateLumaPlane90(const unsigned char *src, unsigned char *dst,
                       size_t size, size_t width, size_t height)
{
    const unsigned char *endp;
    const unsigned char *base;
    int j;

    endp = src + size;
    for (base = endp - width; base < endp; base++) {
        src = base;
        for (j = 0; j < height; j++, src -= width)
        {
            *dst++ = *src;
        }

    }
}


//
// nv12 chroma plane is interleaved chroma values that map
// from one pair of chroma to 4 pixels:
//
// Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4
// Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8   U1,V1 -> chroma values for block  Y1 Y2
// Y9 Ya Yb Yc                                     Y5 Y6
// Yd Ye Yf Yg
// -----------   U2,V2 -> chroma values for block  Y3 Y4
// U1 V1 U2 V2                                     Y7 Y8
// U3 V3 U4 V4
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void rotateChromaPlane90(const unsigned char *src, unsigned char *dst,
                         size_t size, size_t width, size_t height)
{
    // src will start at upper right, moving down to bottom
    // then left 1 col and down...
    //
    // dest will start at end and go to 0

    int row = 0;
    int col = (int) width;
    int src_offset = col - 1;
    int dst_offset = (int) size - 2;

    while (src_offset >= 0)
    {
        dst[dst_offset] = src[src_offset];
        dst[dst_offset+1] = src[src_offset+1];
        dst_offset -= 2;

        src_offset += width;
        row++;

        if (row >= height) {
            col -= 2;
            src_offset = col;
            row = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a sample of me calling these funcs from android native:

```
  // first rotate the Y plane
  rotateLumaPlane90((unsigned char *) encode_buffer, 
                     rotate_buffer, 
                     yPlaneSize,
                     gInputWidth, 
                     gInputHeight);


  // now rotate the U and V planes
  rotateChromaPlane90((unsigned char *) encode_buffer + yPlaneSize,
                       rotate_buffer + yPlaneSize,
                       yPlaneSize / 2,
                       gInputWidth,
                       gInputHeight/2);
```

Notice the last param to the `rotateChromaPlane90` is the height of the original image/2. I should probably just change the chroma rotate function to make that less error-prone.

When flipped to the back facing camera I then found I needed to rotate 90* in the opposite direction (or 270*) so I also have a 270* variation as:

```
// rotate luma image plane 270*
//
//             +-------------+
//             |^            |
//             |^ (base dir) |
//             |^            |
//     base -> +-------------+ <- endp
//                          ^
//             <----------  |
//              (dst dir)  dst
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void rotateLumaPlane270(unsigned char *src,
                        register unsigned char *dst,
                        int size, int width, int height)
{
    unsigned char *endp;
    register unsigned char *base;
    int j;

    endp = src + size;
    dst = dst + size - 1;
    for (base = endp - width; base < endp; base++) {
        src = base;
        for (j = 0; j < height; j++, src -= width)
        {
            *dst-- = *src;
        }

    }
}

//
// nv21 chroma plane is interleaved chroma values that map
// from one pair of chroma to 4 pixels:
//
// Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4
// Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8   U1,V1 -> chroma values for block  Y1 Y2
// Y9 Ya Yb Yc                                     Y5 Y6
// Yd Ye Yf Yg
// -----------   U2,V2 -> chroma values for block  Y3 Y4
// U1 V1 U2 V2                                     Y7 Y8
// U3 V3 U4 V4
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void rotateChromaPlane270(unsigned char *src,
                          register unsigned char *dst,
                          int size, int width, int height)
{
    // src will start at upper right, moving down to bottom
    // then left 1 col and down...
    //
    // dest will start at 0 and go til end

    int row = 0;
    int col = width;
    int src_offset = col - 1;
    int dst_offset = 0;

    while (src_offset > 0)
    {
      dst[dst_offset++] = src[src_offset];
      dst[dst_offset++] = src[src_offset+1];

      src_offset += width;
      row++;

      if (row >= height) {
        col -= 2;
        src_offset = col;
        row = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have also a renderscript version of this ?

Comment: @aminakoy sorry, I don't

Comment: So even running it via JNI, the performance would not change as if written in java? As it is running on CPU but not GPU.