# Rotate YUV420 android.media.Image Android

Tags: android, image, kotlin, yuv

I am trying to get multiple images and put them through an algorithm. The format that I am using is `YUV_420_8888` like this:

```
streamImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
  imageSize.width,
  imageSize.height,
  ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,
  30
)
```

After that, I need to convert the result `android.media.Image` instance (the result image) into an RGB byte array. I am doing this with this extension function called with `image.planes`:

```
fun Array<Plane>.YUV_420_888_toRGB(
    context: Context,
    width: Int,
    height: Int
): ByteArray {
    // Get the three image planes
    val planes: Array<Plane> = this
    var buffer: ByteBuffer = planes[0].buffer
    buffer.rewind()

    val y = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
    buffer.get(y)
    buffer = planes[1].buffer

    val u = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
    buffer.get(u)
    buffer = planes[2].buffer

    val v = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
    buffer.get(v)

    // get the relevant RowStrides and PixelStrides
    // (we know from documentation that PixelStride is 1 for y)
    val yRowStride = planes[0].rowStride
    val uvRowStride =
        planes[1].rowStride // we know from documentation that RowStride is the same for u and v.
    val uvPixelStride =
        planes[1].pixelStride // we know from documentation that PixelStride is the same for u and v.

    // rs creation just for demo. Create rs just once in onCreate and use it again.
    val rs = RenderScript.create(context)
    //RenderScript rs = MainActivity.rs;
    val mYuv420 = ScriptC_yuv420888(rs)
    // Y,U,V are defined as global allocations, the out-Allocation is the Bitmap.
    // Note also that uAlloc and vAlloc are 1-dimensional while yAlloc is 2-dimensional.
    val typeUcharY: Type.Builder = Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs))
    typeUcharY.setX(yRowStride).setY(height)

    val yAlloc = Allocation.createTyped(rs, typeUcharY.create())
    yAlloc.copy1DRangeFrom(0, y.size, y)
    mYuv420.set_ypsIn(yAlloc)

    val typeUcharUV: Type.Builder = Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs))
    // note that the size of the u's and v's are as follows:
    // (  (width/2)*PixelStride + padding  ) * (height/2)
    // = (RowStride) * (height/2)
    typeUcharUV.setX(u.size)

    val uAlloc = Allocation.createTyped(rs, typeUcharUV.create())
    uAlloc.copyFrom(u)
    mYuv420._uIn = uAlloc

    val vAlloc = Allocation.createTyped(rs, typeUcharUV.create())
    vAlloc.copyFrom(v)
    mYuv420._vIn = vAlloc
    // handover parameters
    mYuv420._picWidth = width.toLong()
    mYuv420._uvRowStride = uvRowStride.toLong()
    mYuv420._uvPixelStride = uvPixelStride.toLong()

    val outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
        rs,
        outBitmap,
        Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
        Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT
    )

    val lo = LaunchOptions()
    lo.setX(
        0,
        width
    ) // by this we ignore the y’s padding zone, i.e. the right side of x between width and yRowStride

    lo.setY(0, height)
    mYuv420.forEach_doConvert(outAlloc, lo)
    outAlloc.copyTo(outBitmap)

    return outBitmap.toByteArray()
}
```

The problem I am having is that this resulted byte array is rotated. I tried fixing it with this suggestion: [Rotate an YUV byte array on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167976/rotate-an-yuv-byte-array-on-android)

**BUT**, the resulted byte array after the algorithm above has half as many items as the first one (some loss here).

I was thinking that the easiest solution for this would be to rotate directly the Image, instead of the byte array.