# Android CameraX how to rotate output video

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediacodec, android-camerax

I use the following versions of CameraX dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta04"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha11"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha11"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-beta04"
```

And try to encode output video from the camera into H264 using android `MediaCodec` and decode it back and show the result video on a SurfaceView, everything works fine except that the video on a SurfaceView is conterclockwise rotated by 90 degrees in portrait mode and has no rotation in landscape mode.

My code of capturing video from the camera looks like this:

```
private lateinit var yData: ByteArray  //
private lateinit var uData: ByteArray  // store YUV data from camera
private lateinit var vData: ByteArray  //

imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder().setBackpressureStrategy ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST).build()
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { imageProxy ->
    if (imageProxy.image == null || imageProxy.planes.size < 3) return@Analyzer

    for (i in 0 until 3) {
        val plane = imageProxy.image!!.planes[i]
        val bytes = ByteArray(plane.buffer.remaining())
        plane.buffer.get(bytes)
        when(i) {
            0 -> yData = bytes
            1 -> uData = bytes
            2 -> vData = bytes
        }
    }
    imageProxy.close()

    // send yData, uData, vData to encoder ...
})
```

To solve the problem I tried to use: `imageAnalysis.targetRotation = Surface.ROTATION_0` and other values but it doesn't work at all - the decoded video still rotated.

Also I tried to rotate YUV data that I get from the camera using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800979/12629252) answer and this time I succeeded in rotating my video, BUT the colors of the video suddenly gets dark and I have no idea why.. but if I don't rotate my video the colors are perfect.

**So my question is:** how can I correctly rotate my video without colors distortion? The way when I need to rotate my SurfaceView isn't fit for me. And I repeat - the problem exactly with decoded video that I first get from camera and encode to H264 and not with preview from camera, the preview from camera works fine.

[image: my source video without use of any ways that I mentioned above] Here my source video without use of any ways that I mentioned above.

[image: my video when I use rotation of it's YUV data] And here my video when I use rotation of it's YUV data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution - I made an android [library](https://github.com/theeasiestway/android-yuv-utils), based on Google's [libyuv](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/) library for easy and fast scaling, rotating and mirroring frames from android Camera2 or CameraX api.

Comment: Is this (still?) the only way to rotate CameraX video output? My video has been recording in portrait despite landscape and I've been scratching my head on it.

Comment: @Grant not sure but you can try to rotate a surface that displays the video