# Rotate YUV420/NV21 Image in android

Tags: android, image-processing, rotation, yuv

In PreviewCall back of surface we are getting YUV420SP format in camera Preview but due to wrong rotation of that image I want to perform correct rotation of YUV image as I need to send it through network.so correct rotation need to be applied.

I found this link it does correct rotation but image loose the color.

http://www.wordsaretoys.com/2013/10/25/roll-that-camera-zombie-rotation-and-coversion-from-yv12-to-yuv420planar/

also checked [Rotate an YUV byte array on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167976/rotate-an-yuv-byte-array-on-android?rq=1) but it does not show image properly.

I do have checked links on stckoverflow but none of them have satisfactory answer about correctly using the code in android environment.

do any one have idea how to correctly rotate NV21 Image bytes[] with retaining its color information correctly.

Comment: Are you looking for native code or Java?  Do you fully understand the format of a YUV planar image?  The luma plane is at the front followed by the chroma plane.

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to rotate NV21, following code will be helpful. (I modified the code [from here](http://www.wordsaretoys.com/2013/10/25/roll-that-camera-zombie-rotation-and-coversion-from-yv12-to-yuv420planar/))

```
public static void rotateNV21(byte[] input, byte[] output, int width, int height, int rotation) {
        boolean swap = (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270);
        boolean yflip = (rotation == 90 || rotation == 180);
        boolean xflip = (rotation == 270 || rotation == 180);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int xo = x, yo = y;
                int w = width, h = height;
                int xi = xo, yi = yo;
                if (swap) {
                    xi = w * yo / h;
                    yi = h * xo / w;
                }
                if (yflip) {
                    yi = h - yi - 1;
                }
                if (xflip) {
                    xi = w - xi - 1;
                }
                output[w * yo + xo] = input[w * yi + xi];
                int fs = w * h;
                int qs = (fs >> 2);
                xi = (xi >> 1);
                yi = (yi >> 1);
                xo = (xo >> 1);
                yo = (yo >> 1);
                w = (w >> 1);
                h = (h >> 1);
                // adjust for interleave here
                int ui = fs + (w * yi + xi) * 2;
                int uo = fs + (w * yo + xo) * 2;
                // and here
                int vi = ui + 1;
                int vo = uo + 1;
                output[uo] = input[ui]; 
                output[vo] = input[vi]; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to work for 180 degs, but the 90 and 270 deg rotation leaves the image distorted.

Comment: I have tried it for 270 degrees and found out the problem that the size of the picture stand still.

Comment: agree images are distorted please update your code for 90 degrees as well.

Answer (score -1):

Eddy Yong`s code works well with 180 degrees only, but gained some upvotes in here and a lot of copy-pastes in other SO topics and other similar (e.g. github discussions), so I've decided to leave here proper answer for future researchers, and rotation method, which works for 90, 180 and 270 deegres

```
public static byte[] rotateNV21(final byte[] yuv,
                                final int width,
                                final int height,
                                final int rotation)
{
  if (rotation == 0) return yuv;
  if (rotation % 90 != 0 || rotation < 0 || rotation > 270) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("0 <= rotation < 360, rotation % 90 == 0");
  }

  final byte[]  output    = new byte[yuv.length];
  final int     frameSize = width * height;
  final boolean swap      = rotation % 180 != 0;
  final boolean xflip     = rotation % 270 != 0;
  final boolean yflip     = rotation >= 180;

  for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      final int yIn = j * width + i;
      final int uIn = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width + (i & ~1);
      final int vIn = uIn       + 1;

      final int wOut     = swap  ? height              : width;
      final int hOut     = swap  ? width               : height;
      final int iSwapped = swap  ? j                   : i;
      final int jSwapped = swap  ? i                   : j;
      final int iOut     = xflip ? wOut - iSwapped - 1 : iSwapped;
      final int jOut     = yflip ? hOut - jSwapped - 1 : jSwapped;

      final int yOut = jOut * wOut + iOut;
      final int uOut = frameSize + (jOut >> 1) * wOut + (iOut & ~1);
      final int vOut = uOut + 1;

      output[yOut] = (byte)(0xff & yuv[yIn]);
      output[uOut] = (byte)(0xff & yuv[uIn]);
      output[vOut] = (byte)(0xff & yuv[vIn]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

[originally posted by jake in this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853401/camera-pixels-rotated)